# Elemenntary OS Wingpanel not loading

Tags: wingpanel, elementary-project

I was just browsing on Chrome when I decided to change my volume through the wingpanel. It wasn't responding and it disappeared. I decided to restart my laptop to see if that would fix my problem but alas no luck.

I have tried wingpanel & command it returns with the following [message](https://i.imgur.com/oQPlT4V.png)

Please help.

Thank you